# back end and front end options for youtube-type site

Tags: youtube, compare, video-streaming, frontend, backend

What are the best front-end and back-end languages and database setups for a youtube-type site that manages user accounts, security, streaming, database manipulation, etc. I am looking to start a project incorporating multiple developers and I need to understand the pros and cons of different options including things such as scalability, security, efficiency, easy-to-learn, etc. to decide on a standard for the project. Please try to keep opinions out of the comparisons unless they represent a general consensus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking further into it I have found a few different frameworks, especially backend.

For security reasons, I have decide on Laravel, a very robust PHP framework. It handles templating, routing (pretty URLs), security checks, database management, and tons of other cool features.

Frontend will simply be jQuery because Laravel achieves most of the tasks Javascript frameworks are created for,

And finally Bootstrap 4 with SASS to expedite CSS writing.

Hopefully this helps someone!